# Converting a List of Dictionaries to Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have this code:

```
import urllib.request, json
url = "https://api.wto.org/timeseries/v1/indicator_categories?lang=1"

hdr ={
    # Request headers
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
    'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': '21cda66d75fc4010b8b4d889f4af6ccd',
    }

req = urllib.request.Request(url, headers=hdr)

req.get_method = lambda: 'GET'
response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
    #print(response.getcode())
var = print(response.read().decode('ASCII'))
```

I tried this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(var)
```

I am only getting an empty dataframe. The data is lost somehow. What am I doing wrong?

Also tried:

```
var = (response.read().decode('ASCII'))
```

This returns Byte String which I am not able to convert using eval():

```
eval(var)
```

> NameError: name 'null' is not defined

I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: You are setting `var` to the output of `print()` which is `None`.

Comment: I tried without print. It returned byte string which I converted  using eval(). Still it gave some error.

Comment: It's a json string. You need to parse it. `import json` then `pd.DataFrame(json.loads(var))` Assuming `var = response.read()` without the print.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import urllib.request, json
import pandas as pd

url = "https://api.wto.org/timeseries/v1/indicator_categories?lang=1"
hdr = {
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
    'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': '21cda66d75fc4010b8b4d889f4af6ccd',
}

# Prepare and make the request
req = urllib.request.Request(url, headers=hdr)
with urllib.request.urlopen(req) as response:
    data = response.read().decode('utf-8')  # Decode response

# Load JSON data
json_data = json.loads(data)

# Determine if the JSON data is a list or a dictionary
if isinstance(json_data, dict):
    # If the JSON is a dictionary, you might want to access a particular key
    # Adjust 'your_key_here' to the actual key you need, e.g., 'results'
    if 'your_key_here' in json_data:
        data_to_load = json_data['your_key_here']
        df = pd.DataFrame(data_to_load)
    else:
        print("Expected key not found in JSON data")
elif isinstance(json_data, list):
    # If the JSON is directly a list
    df = pd.DataFrame(json_data)
else:
    print("Unexpected JSON structure")

print(df.head())  # Display the first few rows to verify
```

Comment: This does not work for (Same data source) this: url = "https://api.wto.org/timeseries/v1/data?i=TP_A_0010&r=all&p=default&ps=default&pc=default&spc=false&fmt=json&mode=full&dec=default&off=0&max=500&head=H&lang=1&meta=false"

Comment: What changes should I make to this code?